# finding top k elements in array python without heapq or sorting

Tags: python

I am trying to find the top k elements of a list in python without using heapq or sorting the list.

This is what I tried,

```
list = [20,4,67,22,445,1,34]
k = 3
newList=[]

for i in range(0,k):
    newList.append(list[i])
for i in list:
    mini = min(newList)
    if i <= mini:
        continue
    else:
        newList.remove(mini)
        newList.append(i)
print newList
```

But i am getting 67,67,445. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is apparent when you add some tracing:

```
>>> list = [20,4,67,22,445,1,34]
>>> k = 3
>>> newList=[]
>>> 
>>> for i in range(0,k):
...     newList.append(list[i])
... 
>>> for i in list:
...     mini = min(newList)
...     if i <= mini:
...         continue
...     else:
...         print newList
...         print "Replacing {0} with {1}".format(mini, i)
...         newList.remove(mini)
...         newList.append(i)
...         print newList
...         print '-' * 20
... 
[20, 4, 67]
Replacing 4 with 20
[20, 67, 20]
--------------------
[20, 67, 20]
Replacing 20 with 67
[67, 20, 67]
--------------------
[67, 20, 67]
Replacing 20 with 22
[67, 67, 22]
--------------------
[67, 67, 22]
Replacing 22 with 445
[67, 67, 445]
```

You already have 67 in the list when you iterate over it and add it a second time.

I would rewrite it as:

```
>>> numbers = [20,4,67,22,445,1,34]
>>> k = 3
>>> newList = numbers[:k]
>>> 
>>> for i in numbers[k:]:
...     mini = min(newList)
...     if i > mini:
...         print "Replacing {0} with {1}".format(mini, i)
...         newList.remove(mini)
...         newList.append(i)
... 
Replacing 4 with 22
Replacing 20 with 445
Replacing 22 with 34
>>> print newList
[67, 445, 34]
```

I would not name your list `list`, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it as:

```
a = [20,4,67,22,445,1,34]
k = 3
newList=[]

for i in range(k):
    pos = a.index(max(a))
    newList.append(a[pos])
    a.pop(pos)

>>> print newList
[67, 445, 34]
```

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me where I am wrong with my implementation?

Comment: @Naren, Your problem is in `for i in range(0,k):
    newList.append(list[i])`

Answer (score 0):

you have 67 in your newlist at beginning and the 67 never pop out

Comment: This may well be the correct answer, but could you make it a little more complete? It isn't very high quality as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from hughdbrown has one bug that I noticed. 
If the list has similar entries, then the result would just display one of those entries. 
For example, if the list is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]`, the result would display `[3, 4, 5]` instead of `[4, 5, 5]`